# Как работают замыкания (нюансы)?

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Что такое замыкания мне понятно, но в ходе их исследования возникли нюансы:

Есть код:

```
<script>
    function createCounter() {
       var numberOfCalls = 0;

       return function() {
          return ++numberOfCalls;
       }
    }

    var fn = createCounter();

    alert(fn()); //1
    alert(fn()); //2
    alert(fn()); //3

</script>
```

Не могу осознать благодаря чему переменная **numberOfCalls** в функции **createCounter** не обнуляется? Это фишка такая или этому есть разумное объяснение?

Comment: А у вас есть разумное объяснение, почему она должна обнуляться? Или это фишка такая?

Comment: мне кажется что при каждом вызове функции переменная инициализироваться нулем должна как и написано в коде, а на деле это не так. тяжело это осознать после языка С++

Comment: Так и происходит. Вы вызываете один раз функцию, она инициализируется нулем. Потом вы вызываете три раза другую функцию, которая увеличивает её значение на единицу.

Comment: Значит все таки это фишка. Я просто не понял зачем такой механизм удерживания значений придуман, когда для функции можно применять свойства которые сохраняют свои значения. PS в С++ для этого есть ключевое слово static а в javascript этому целая конструкция посвещена (

Comment: Нет, это не аналог статических значений. Ну может отдалённо, конечно.

Comment: @perfect замыкания в javascript - это тогда уж аналог замыканий в C++ :) В каком-то из свежих стандартов они там появились.

Comment: @PavelMayorov. я как раз начал осваивать новый стандарт языка, но  замыканиями раньше столкнулся в javascript чем плюсах. значит их теперь мне проще будет освоить раз уже знаю что это такое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Вы вызываете один раз функцию `createCounter`".

"Замыкание" - создание объекта, содержащего экземпляры всех переменных из внешних областей видимости, используемых функцией.

Вызовите функцию еще раз , а потом начинайте вызывать два результата в произвольном порядке:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function createCounter() {
    var numberOfCalls = 0;

    return function() {
      return ++numberOfCalls;
    };
  }

  function appendOutput(aText) {
    $("#output").append(aText + "<br/>");
  }

  $("#btnRun").click(function() {
    $("#output").html("");

    var fn1 = createCounter();
    var fn2 = createCounter();

    appendOutput("fn1: " + fn1());
    appendOutput("fn1: " + fn1());
    appendOutput("fn1: " + fn1());

    appendOutput("fn2: " + fn2());
    appendOutput("fn2: " + fn2());

    appendOutput("fn1: " + fn1());
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btnRun">Run</button>
<div id="output">output</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Её [переменную] один раз инициализировали, возвращённая функция находится вложеннее, и, так как переменная используется в функции, сборщик не убирает её.
[Полезное чтение почему так происходит](https://learn.javascript.ru/closures).

Answer (score 0):

Особенность вложенных функций состоит в том, чтобы получать значения из нее. В данном случае, внутри одной функции создаётся другая и возвращается в качестве результата. В разработке интерфейсов это совершенно стандартный приём, функция затем может назначаться как обработчик действий посетителя.

```
function createCounter() {
// LexicalEnvironment = { numberOfCalls: undefined }

var numberOfCalls = 0;

// LexicalEnvironment = { numberOfCalls : 0 }

return function() { // [[Scope]] -> LexicalEnvironment (**)
return numberOfCalls++;
};
}
```

Как видно, мы получили независимый счётчик `function()`, каждый из которых, незаметным снаружи образом, сохраняет текущее количество вызовов.

Если подробнее описать происходящее:

1) В строке (*) запускается `createCounter()`. При этом создаётся `LexicalEnvironment` для переменных текущего вызова. В функции есть одна переменная `var numberOfCalls`, которая станет свойством этого объекта. Она изначально инициализируется в `undefined`, затем в процессе выполнения получит значение 0.

2) В процессе выполнения `createCounter()` создаёт функцию в строке (**). При создании эта функция получает внутреннее свойство `[[Scope]]` со ссылкой на текущий `LexicalEnvironment`.

3) Далее вызов `createCounter()` завершается.